# API for what happened on this day?

Tags: api

Is there an API which can be used to get data about what happened On this day in history .
Like the wikipedia home page shows On this day these events happened in history and these are the birthdays today  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia produces this data based on the extensive data and tagging of articles etc in its DB. Your best bet is probably going to be to scrape a wiki page that shows this.

Note: Don't fall foul of copyrights etc ! - There I said it. Can't get sued now!

**Update 2021:**

As mentioned by @sagun-raj-lage, it looks like there is now an API you can use officially, with an endpoint for onthisday: see https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/#/Feed/onThisDay

Comment: I am not asking specifically for wikipedia data on historical events by date any other sources for API are fine

Comment: I'm saying that they aren't going to exist due to the volumne of data it requires. This is your best shot (even if you don't use wikipedia as the source.)

Comment: Check out this small Python API which pulls data from Wikipedia https://github.com/keheliya/histopy

Comment: Check this: http://history.muffinlabs.com/#api

Comment: You can check out this documentation for that kind of API. https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/#/Feed/onThisDay